# Using parameters in Azure Data Factory Data Mapping Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using a 'mapping data flow' activity in ADF to extract and load some records. I have created 2 parameters in the data flow activity - table_name, schema_name - which I'm trying to use to make the same activity work for multiple tables.

In the Source Options tab on Source(within data flow activity) I have the following query -

```sql
select * from '{$SchemaName}'.'{$TableName}'
```

I'm getting the following error message when I debug -

```json
{
  "message": "Job failed due to reason: at Source 'source1'(Line 2/Col 11): Column operands are not allowed in literal expressions. Details:at Source 'source1'(Line 2/Col 11): Column operands are not allowed in literal expressions",
  "failureType": "UserError",
  "target": "GetLatestData",
  "errorCode": "DFExecutorUserError"
}
```

Anyone have any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Would you mind copy/paste the data flow script for this data flow? Go to the ADF data flow designer and click the Script button.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this expression:

```
"select * from {$SchemaName}.{$TableName}"
```

My test:

1.create two parameters:
[image]

2.click 'Add dynamic content [Alt+P]'
[image]

3.type this expression: `"select * from {$SchemaName}.{$TableName}"`
[image]

Data preview:
[image]

Comment: If you think my answer helps you, you could mark it as answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This does NOT work. I tried the same with my use case "SELECT * FROM PharmacyMaster WHERE NationalProviderIdentifier in ({$parameter1})" and it does not work.